# boost python make_constructor and custodians and ward

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

Suppose I have the following two C++ classes (which I can't modify):

```
struct A
{
    // stuff
};

struct B
{
    // B will internally hold a reference to a
    B(A& a, some_cpp_only_type arg);
};
```

I am trying to wrap the B class and hiding the `some_cpp_only_type` argument from the Python interface (there is no alternative constructor for `B` without this argument).

I have the following wrapper code right now:

```
using namespace boost::python;

boost::shared_ptr<B> make_B(A& a)
{
    return boost::make_shared<B>(a, get_cpp_only_instance());
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module)
{
    class_<B, boost::noncopyable>("B", no_init)
      .def("__init__", make_constructor(&make_B));
}
```

Right now this works because I'm holding a reference to the wrapped `A` object inside of Python. However, I would really like to keep this around at least until the instance of `B` is destroyed. I tried adding a `with_custodian_and_ward_postcall` call policy to `make_constructor`, but I get several pages of meaningless compiler errors (even from Clang). Here's the modified not working code:

```
using namespace boost::python;

boost::shared_ptr<B> make_B(A& a)
{
    return boost::make_shared<B>(a, get_cpp_only_instance());
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module)
{
    class_<B, boost::noncopyable>("B", no_init)
      .def("__init__", make_constructor(&make_B, with_custodian_and_ward_postcall<0,1>()));
}
```

How do I properly specify the call policy when using `make_constructor`?

**Alternative attempt using make_function**

I tried using the solution [Tanner Sansbury posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36266571/558546) of wrapping with `make_function` instead, but this time even though the compile succeeds, I get a `ValueError` from inside of Python:

> No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: A

For reference, here is the code I tried which uses `make_function` (I get the same error with and without the custodian/ward call policy):

```
using namespace boost::python;

boost::shared_ptr<B> make_B(A& a)
{
    return boost::make_shared<B>(a, get_cpp_only_instance());
}

void inter_make_B(object self, A& a)
{
    auto constructor = make_constructor(&make_B);
    constructor(self, a);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module)
{
    class_<B, boost::noncopyable>("B", no_init)
      .def("__init__", make_function(&inter_make_B, with_custodian_and_ward<1,2>()));
}
```

How do I properly write the wrapper for `B` which manages memory correctly without modifying the `B` class?

Comment: I think it should be something like:

    python::make_constructor(&ItemFactory, 
             python::return_value_policy<
                    python::with_custodian_and_ward_postcall<0, 2>>()))

However, that still gets me the boost::python error message:
::MAKE_CONSTRUCTOR_SUPPLIES_ITS_OWN_RESULT_CONVERTER_THAT_WOULD_OVERRIDE_YOURS::

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is 3 years old, but I was myself looking for this and unable to find any solution working out of the box with minimal modification of the original code. I finally managed to get it to work thanks to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983556/boost-python-tie-lifetime-of-argument-to-returned-value-using-return-internal-r).

Here is a mock based on the snippet you provided:

```
using namespace boost::python;

boost::shared_ptr<B> make_B(A& a)
{
    return boost::make_shared<B>(a, get_cpp_only_instance());
}

void make_B_wrapper(object self, A& a)
{
    auto constructor = make_constructor(&make_B);
    constructor(self, a);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module)
{
    class_<B, boost::noncopyable>("B", no_init)
      .def("__init__", &make_B_wrapper, with_custodian_and_ward_postcall<1,2>());
}
```

---

And here is a complete working [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52a2732040a8434e) demonstrating this approach:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> 
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp> 
#include <iostream>

namespace python = boost::python;
  
/// @brief Mockup class with verbose construction and destruction.
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() { std::cout << "Foo() " << this << std::endl; }
  ~Foo() { std::cout << "~Foo() " << this << std::endl; }
};

/// @brief Mockup class with verbose construction and destruction.
class Bar
{
public:
  Bar() { std::cout << "Bar() " << this << std::endl; }
  ~Bar() { std::cout << "~Bar() " << this << std::endl; }
};

/// @brief Mockup factory function.
boost::shared_ptr<Foo> makeFoo(std::shared_ptr<Bar> & /* unused */)
{
  return boost::make_shared<Foo>();
}

static void makeFooWrapper(python::object & self, std::shared_ptr<Bar> & bar)
{
    auto constructor = python::make_constructor(&makeFoo);
    constructor(self, bar);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  python::class_<Bar, std::shared_ptr<Bar>, boost::noncopyable>("Bar", python::init<>());

  python::class_<Foo, std::shared_ptr<Foo>, boost::noncopyable>("Foo", python::no_init)
    .def("__init__", &makeFooWrapper,
                     python::with_custodian_and_ward_postcall<1, 2>());
}
```